# GNU Makefile Included file (re-)making order

Tags: makefile, include

I have a Makefile of approximately following structure:

```
SRC = some_file.c

include component.mk

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.d)
DEP = $(SRC:.c=.d)

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
include $(DEP)
endif

all: some_file.o

$(DEP): component.mk

component.mk:
    echo "CPPFLAGS += -Iheaders_dir/" > $@
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -MM -MT $(@:.d=.o) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(DEP) component.mk
```

The issue is that the `.d` files fail to create due to missing definitions in `$(CPPFLAGS)`; these definitions, however, are defined inside `component.mk`, which is included above.

It seems that `make` tries to (re-)make missing/modified includes <strike>even before including those, that do not need to be (re-)made</strike>. It seems to simply performs inclusions in reverse order (??) as they appear in the `Makefile` and (re-)making missing files along the way.

Is there some solution here other than moving `include component.mk` below `include $(DEP)`, since this seems to break other things in my actual `Makefile`.

**EDIT:** Actually, this seems to be issue only when `component.mk` is also (re-)made by some rule in the Makefile, so `make` correctly includes files that do not need to be (re-)made before those, that do need to be (re-)made.

**EDIT:** Even this does not seem to help:

```
$(DEP): component.mk
```

Although the `component.mk` gets made before `.d` files, however that does not seem to influence the inclusion order. Nor it seem to help to move `include component.mk` below `include $(DEP)`, `make` seems try to (re-)make all inclusions before actually including them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that the `component.mk` is an included makefile but the `*.d` files are also included makefiles. make always tries to re-build the included makefiles but you cannot force an order on this. If all you expect from `component.mk` is adding options to `CPPFLAGS`, why don't you simply use target-specific variables, instead, and get rid of `component.mk`?

```
SRC = some_file.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP = $(SRC:.c=.d)

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
include $(DEP)
endif

all: some_file.o

%.o %.d: CPPFLAGS += -Iheaders_dir/

%.o: %.c %.d
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -MM -MT $(@:.d=.o) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(DEP)
```

Another option would be to use a recursive make invocation (the first one building `component.mk` and invoking the second one) but it would probably be uselessly complicated.

Note: I fixed a typo in the definition of `OBJ` and added `%.d` to the prerequisites of `%.o`.

Comment: The code in my question was just simplification, there is no simple way to get rid of `component.mk`. However, however I solved it by making `component.mk` 'static', i.e. it is not made by the Makefile (there was no urgent need to do so). This solves the issue, since `make` will include these 'static' files before generated ones.